# TikZ graph drawing: edge option conflicts with chain group

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I thought that the following two graphs are the same.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph{1--{2,3}};
    \tikz\graph{1--[]{2,3}};
\end{document}
```

But they result

[image] and [image].

It is supposed to be so? I found this because I need to insert some edge options like `[red,thick]`. But usually I create empty nodes like `\tikz\graph{/--[foobar]{/,/}};` to make it short. Any alternatives?

Comment: Besides accepting an answer you should also up vote it:  [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) and perhaps [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @PeterGrill Sorry I was looking for that syntax in the manual. It does solve my problem. The point is that I cannot get its logic...

Comment: If it solved your problem, then it certainly deserves an up vote. If you have trouble understanding the logic or the syntax you could either ask the one who answered it via a comment or even post a new question specifically on the syntax or logic. If you are having difficulty understanding it, chances are good that others will to, so a separate question on the syntax might be helpful to others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the syntax to styling edges.
Here is an example of how to do it :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph{1--{2,3}};
    \tikz\graph{1--{2[>green!75!black], 3[>{thick,red}]}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Reminder: this is (currently) described in §19.6.3 Options For Incoming and Outgoing Edges

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Kpym is not correct. There is indeed such a syntax for styling edges as described in [§19.6.1 Options For All Edges Between Two Groups (p. 276)](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=276):

> When you write `… ->[options] …` somewhere inside your graph specification, this typically cause one
>   or more edges to be created between the nodes in the chain group before the `->` and the nodes in the chain group following it. The `options` are applied to all of them.

The OP is simply missing a space after the `]` and before the `{`. Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
    \tikz\graph{1--{2,3}};
    \tikz\graph{1--[] {2,3}}; % ← space added between ] and {

    % This also works:
    \tikz\graph{1--[]{2,3} }; % ← space added between } and }
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: How come missing a space is a problem in Ti*k*Z? I mean, if it does need such a space, why does the spaceless code compile?

Comment: @Symbol1 Good question. I also don't know the answer to that.

Comment: Anyway I appreciate your confirmation. (about that `--[]` is the official syntax.) I shall do some research myself and we will see whether this question has received enough attention or not.

Comment: Even `\tikz\graph{1--[]{2,3} };` works. Checking the code, something goes awry with `\pgfutil@ifnextchar` as it sees the `2` as the next character and not the `{` (= `\bgroup`). Very weird.