# Problem with the last \foreach of this code : won't compile

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,through,backgrounds}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw[step=5mm, gray, very thin] (-4,-4) grid (4,4) ;
\draw[thin, blue] (-3,0) -- (3,0) ;
\draw[thin, blue] (0,-3) -- (0,3) ;

\draw (2.5,0) -- (1.5,2) -- (0,0);
\draw[dotted] (1.5,1) -- (1.5,2) ;
\draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (1.5,1) ;
\draw (0,0) -- (-0.5,1.5) -- (1.5,2) ;
\draw (0,0) -- (2,-1) -- (2.5,0) ;
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (2.5,0) ;
\draw (2,-1) -- (1.5,2) ;
\draw (0,0) -- (0.5,-1) -- (2,-1) ;
\path [name path = ligne1] (0.5,-1) -- (2.5,0) ;
\path [name path = ligne2] (0,0) -- (2,-1) ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne1 and ligne2, by={ x12 }}];
\draw[dashed] (0.5,-1) -- (x12) ;
\draw[dotted] (x12) -- (2.5,0) ;
\path [name path = ligne3] (1.5,1) -- (0.5,-1) ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne2 and ligne3, by={ x23 }}];
\draw[dashed] (0.5,-1) -- (x23) ;
\draw[dotted] (x23) -- (1.5,1) ;
\draw (-0.5,1.5) -- (-0.5,0.25) -- (0.5,-1) ;
\path [name path = ligne4] (-0.5,0.25) -- (1.5,1) ;
\path [name path = ligne5] (0,0) -- (-0.5,1.5) ;
\path [name path = ligne6] (0,0) -- (1.5,2) ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne4 and ligne5, by={ x45 }}];
\path [name intersections={of= ligne4 and ligne6, by={ x46 }}];
\draw[dashed] (-0.5,0.25) -- (x45) ;
\draw[dashed] (x45) -- (x46)(1.5,1) ;
\draw[dotted] (x46) -- (1.5,1) ;
\draw (0,0) -- (-0.5,0.25) ;
\path [name path = ligne7] (2,-1) -- (1.5,2) ;
\path [name path = ligne8] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,1) ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne7 and ligne8, by={ x78 }}];
\draw[dotted] (2.5,0) -- (x78) ;
\draw[dotted ] (x78) -- (1.5,1) ;
\path [name path = ligne9] (-0.5,1.5) -- (1.5,1) ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne6 and ligne9, by={ x69 }}];
\draw[dashed] (-0.5,1.5) -- (x69) ;
\draw[dotted] (x69) -- (1.5,1) ;
\path [name path = ligne10] (0,0) -- (2.5,0) ;
\path [name path=cercle1] (0,0) circle [radius = 1] ;
\path [name intersections={of= ligne10 and cercle1, by={ a }}];
\path [name intersections={of= ligne6 and cercle1, by={ b }}];
\path [name path = ligne11] (2.5,0) -- (1.5,2) ;

\foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
    {\path [name path = div1\n] (0,0) -- ({2.5 -(1*\n)/10},{(2*\n)/10}) ;
     \path [name intersections={of= cercle1 and div1\n, by={ a\n }}] ;


        } ;

\draw[blue,smooth, name path = arca] plot coordinates {(a0) (a1) (a2) (a3) (a4) (a5) (a6) (a7) (a8) (a9) (a10)} ;

\path[name path = cercle2] (0,0) circle [x radius = 1cm, y radius =0.4cm] ;
\foreach \n in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
{\path [name path = div2\n] (0,0) -- ({2.5 -(1*\n)/10},{(1*\n)/10}) ;
    \path [name intersections={of= cercle2 and div2\n, by={ b\n }}] ;
} ;
\draw[green,smooth, name path = arcb] plot coordinates {(b0) (b1) (b2) (b3) (b4) (b5) (b6) (b7) (b8) (b9) (b10)} ;

\path [name path=prearcc] (a10) -- (b10) ;
\coordinate (c) at ($(a10)!0.5!(b10)$) ;


\draw [name path = cercle3]
      let \p1 = ($ (a10) - (c) $),
          \n2 = {veclen(\x1,\y1)}
      in
          (c) circle [x radius = 0.25mm, y radius = \n2,rotate = -11]    ;


\coordinate (c') at ($(a10) - (b10)$) ;
\coordinate (c'') at ($0.1*(c')$) ;


\foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
{\path [draw,red,name path = divnew\i] (c) -- ($ { \i * (c'')} $) ;
    \path [name intersections={of= cercle3 and divnew\i, by={ c\i }}] ;
} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello everybody ! If someone could halp me with the last lines (last \foreach) of this code... It causes the compilation to stop... I've been trying to fox it for hours... Thanks to anyone who may help : )

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Nice code example!

Comment: I haven't tested but looks like you have no intersections if that's the error location

Comment: You wrote `($0.1*(c')$)` with no accident, so remove `{}` in `(${\i*(c'')}$)`

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I found a solution. Indeed, I removed the {}, and, also, it seems that leaving spaces in ($ { \i * (c'')} $) (between\i and * and (c'')) was seen as an when compiling.

Answer (score 3):

I feel nervous to comment something but... just to enrich this answer.

In the first course of TeX we are taught that if anything gets wrong, add braces. For instance `$10^10$`. However Ti*k*Z works in another way. As @percusse explained in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323703/51022), the core of Ti*k*Z repeatedly check the next character and decide what to do next. It will not work if it meets useless braces. So that is the first lesson: add no braces unless necessary.

Then, Ti*k*Z uses a TeX feature to check your spelling. Borrowing @percusse's example:

```
def\tikz@collect@coordinate@onpath@#1oordinate{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tikz@@collect@coordinate@opt#1}{\tikz@@collect@coordinate@opt#1[]}}%}
```

Similarly, in `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex` it defines:

```
\def\tikz@cc@parse@factor#1*({%
  \pgfmathparse{#1*\tikz@cc@factor}%
  \let\tikz@cc@factor=\pgfmathresult%
  \tikz@cc@coordinate(%)
}
```

So that is the second lesson: add no spaces unless [necessary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238249/51022).